# How to create query for searching enrollment number into the Firebase realtime database for if user entered enrollment number exist or not

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created `String userenrollment` that store user entered enrollment number into it! and My firebase real time database looks like [image: this picture].

and I tried one query but it directly goes to else block saying data doesn't exist!

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query query = ref.child("Information").orderByChild("enrollment").equalTo(userenrollment);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.getChildrenCount()>0) {
            Toast.makeText(loginstudentdemo.this, "User exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(loginstudentdemo.this, "User doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

        Toast.makeText(loginstudentdemo.this, "Database Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: If the enrollment number is the data's key, why not use `ref.child("Information").child(userenrollment)` instead? Also delete that plain text password key or at least store a hash of it not the raw string.

Comment: At first glance the query looks correct for the data structure. Can you show the value of `userenrollment` that you use for testing? Is it a `String`?

Comment: I didn't get your storing value in hash! @samthecodingman

Comment: Yes userenrollment is in String! @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: It is bad practice to store passwords in an plain text form. To prevent storing what the user typed in, you must hash the password (encrypt it into a form that can't be decrypted). Common strategies are to hash the password using either `SHA-256` or `SHA-3`. [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) covers the concept in detail. Ideally you should use Firebase Authentication to handle the passwords & authentication for you. If you are already using Firebase Authentication, there is no need to store the user's password.

Comment: Yess I'm using Firebase Auth for Authentication and storing password! But I can't retrieve Enrollment from realtime database. It always shows snapshot doesn.t exist! So provide some suggestions on that! @samthecodingman